# When is this ClickOnce installer really necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm not a professional programmer yet, I've just started college and I study some things by myself outside of it. I'm doing pretty basic stuff in C#, like console applications and simple stuff for the web in asp.net.

I've noticed that whenever I publish a C# project using Visual Studio 2010, I am obligated to use this "click once" setup wizard for my apps. But I don't really think any of them need a setup program, they are just a executable and maybe a bunch of .dlls which are able to run by just executing them right away.

I fail to see what's the poing of this click once installer? It probably checks if the correct version of the .Net framework is installed and, if not, installs it. But is that all it does? I think this click once is too ugly and if checking the .net version is all it does I'd rather code my own installer using another language which looks better and provides more info about my program.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

Comment: Well, if you have to distribute your application to 200+ client machines and your application gets an update from time to time, it's way easier to just send each user a link to the click once installer once instead of writing an update mechnism yourself or forcing the users to update the application by themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use ClickOnce, that's just an option for how to distribute your app. You could simply build using the Release configuration and then distribute that Release folder (typically `bin\Release`, configured in the project's settings), or use a post-build command to, e.g., build a zip of the assemblies and config(s) you need:

```
del /Q $(SolutionDir)MyApp-win.zip
cd $(OutDir)
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $(SolutionDir)MyApp-win.zip MyApp.exe MyApp.exe.config OtherAssembly.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ClickOnce for smaller apps since it simplifies the distribution of app updates alot.

You don't need to use the ClickOnce installer that is provided by Visual Studio though. You can create your own installer (with a UI that suits you more) that in turn uses ClickOnce under the hood for the heavy lifting.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx.